# Modinfo, /etc/modules and lsmod: incoherent output?

Tags: kernel

I have "`rtc`" in `/etc/modules` but

```
$ modinfo rtc
```

outputs:

```
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module rtc
```

and `lsmod` doesn't show `rtc`

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and kernel are you running. Architecture? I only have `lp` listed in /etc/modules on my 10.04 through 12.04 systems.

Comment: What other lines are in /etc/modules?

Comment: @Robert What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

The legacy real-time-clock driver `rtc` certainly exists:

`./linux-3.2.0/drivers/char/rtc.c`

but I believe it's only used in the module context as an include while building modules for specific RTC devices. For example, here's the rtc drivers available for Ubuntu's Linux kernel 3.2:

```
izx@i5:~/src-kernel$ ls /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/rtc/
rtc-88pm860x.ko  rtc-ds1742.ko    rtc-max6900.ko   rtc-rs5c372.ko
rtc-ab3100.ko    rtc-ds3232.ko    rtc-max6902.ko   rtc-rv3029c2.ko
rtc-ab8500.ko    rtc-ds3234.ko    rtc-max8925.ko   rtc-rx8025.ko
rtc-bq32k.ko     rtc-em3027.ko    rtc-max8998.ko   rtc-rx8581.ko
rtc-bq4802.ko    rtc-fm3130.ko    rtc-mc13xxx.ko   rtc-s35390a.ko
rtc-ds1286.ko    rtc-isl12022.ko  rtc-msm6242.ko   rtc-stk17ta8.ko
rtc-ds1305.ko    rtc-isl1208.ko   rtc-pcf2123.ko   rtc-v3020.ko
rtc-ds1307.ko    rtc-m41t80.ko    rtc-pcf50633.ko  rtc-wm831x.ko
rtc-ds1374.ko    rtc-m41t93.ko    rtc-pcf8563.ko   rtc-wm8350.ko
rtc-ds1390.ko    rtc-m41t94.ko    rtc-pcf8583.ko   rtc-x1205.ko
rtc-ds1511.ko    rtc-m48t35.ko    rtc-r9701.ko
rtc-ds1553.ko    rtc-m48t59.ko    rtc-rp5c01.ko
rtc-ds1672.ko    rtc-m48t86.ko    rtc-rs5c348.ko
```

As Florian asked, why do you need this module? What is your platform? Are you using a specific RTC device?

---

`/etc/modules` is used to load external modules at startup -- the modules (`.ko` files) must first be present under `/lib/modules/your-kernel-version/....`; just having them in `/etc/modules` means nothing.

You can safely remove `rtc` from `/etc/modules`.

Comment: I don't know why it is in /etc/modules and I don't know why if it is there it doesn't appear as loaded. Just that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no kernel module named `rtc` so it can't be loaded and `lsmod` and `modinfo` can't find it.

Why do you think there should be such a module? What do you want to do?

Comment: what does the line rtc in /etc/modules mean then?

Comment: It indeed means "load the module 'rct' at startup". But if that module doesn't exist it just does nothing. Maybe that line is a leftover from an older installation where that module did exist.

Comment: I want to know if I can remove that line or to understand what it is doing there. An older installation? There hasn't been an older installation, only a few previous kernels. If it does not exist, what is /lib/modules/2.6.38-15-generic/kernel/drivers/rtc, then?

Comment: That's a folder that contains some kernel modules.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of rtc drivers built statically into the Ubuntu kernel. Namely rtc_cmos and rtc_m41t80. (I have /dev/rtc and /dev/rtc0 on my 12.04 system, by the way.) rtc_cmos supports the legacy PC cmos real time clock. The other certain i2c real time clocks.

The config file for each built Ubuntu kernel is placed into /boot along with the headers and the kernel image itself so you can see how it was set up.

Built in drivers don't show up in lsmod, for example.

At one time there was a driver simply named rtc, but not now. I'd suggest that some package places that name in /etc/modules.

The Ubuntu kernel source is [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=ubuntu/ubuntu-precise.git;a=summary).